# Unable to retrieve data from multiple Wordpress websites on same server

Tags: customization, get-plugin-data

I am trying to retrieve data from multiple client Wordpress websites on a single php page. So I can monitor all these websites without going through each one.

I am able to display data from one single website. Like this, I am listing all plugin installed on one Wordpress.

```
<?php
  require( './domain1/wp-blog-header.php' );
  if ( ! function_exists( 'get_plugins' ) ) {
    require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php';
  }
  $plugins = get_plugins();
  echo '<h1> ' . get_bloginfo( 'name' ) . '</h1>';
  foreach ( $plugins as $plugin ) {
    echo $plugin['Name'] . '<br />';
  }
?>
```

This works fine as I want. But when I try to do this for multiple website, it does not work but shows data from first website multiple times.

```
<?php
  $websites = array( 'domain1', 'domain2', 'domain3', 'domain4', 'domain5', 'domain6' );

  foreach ( $websites as $website ) {
    $file = './' . $website . '/wp-blog-header.php';
    require( $file );
    if ( ! function_exists( 'get_plugins' ) ) {
      require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php';
    }
    $plugins = get_plugins();
    echo '<h1> ' . get_bloginfo( 'name' ) . '</h1>';
    foreach ( $plugins as $plugin ) {
      echo $plugin['Name'] . '<br />';
    }
  }
?>
```

Why it's only showing details from first domain only? What am I doing wrong?
Can someone help me with this.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have debugging enabled? I can't imagine this will work, one issue I think you're encountering is that constants can't be redefined.

Comment: Yes, debugging was enabled and I did not get any error.

Answer (score 0):

Would you mind if I just leave bread crumbs so you can solve this pazzle ?

1. add filter
2. 'query' hook
3. $wpdb->prefix  & local wpdb prefix
4. value somewhere in *_options table
5. remove_filter
6. show values

Once one wpdb instance declared... you can reach any table in it (beware I said table in one DB). But you can't do what you actually doing right now. YOU WILL GET a fatal error.

Other way is to parse wp-config.php of each site, make mysql connection, query everything, and show it... but that a lame-too-easy way....

Comment: I am not WP expert so don't really know what exactly you are pointing at. Can you show me a simple example.

Comment: Well... you can try to reserch what I am pointing on.